# Transfer erc20 token fail execution reverted

Tags: solidity, transactions, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets

hello I'm trying to user a method from the smart contract and transfer token between different address but I got this error this is a [link for the transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x15d1dec7aaac67d90b72625f59bd060dad6f9c669377b786ec6c761951edb8be)

Error:
`Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]`

this is the code of the function of the contract :

```
   function sendTokensFromCustomerToRetailer(address retailer, address customer, uint256 tokens) public onlyOwner {
        increaseAllowance(customer, tokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
        transferFrom(customer, retailer, tokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(customer);
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(retailer);
    }
```

ERC20Upgradeable code:

```
contract ERC20Upgradeable is Initializable, ContextUpgradeable, IERC20Upgradeable, IERC20MetadataUpgradeable {
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

 function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _transfer(owner, to, amount);
        return true;
    }

 function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _approve(owner, spender, amount);
        return true;
    }


function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        address spender = _msgSender();
        _spendAllowance(from, spender, amount);
        _transfer(from, to, amount);
        return true;
    }

 function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _approve(owner, spender, _allowances[owner][spender] + addedValue);
        return true;
    }

  function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[owner][spender];
        require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero");
        unchecked {
            _approve(owner, spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);
        }

        return true;
    }

 function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[from] = fromBalance - amount;
        }
        _balances[to] += amount;

        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

 function _spendAllowance(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(owner, spender);
        if (currentAllowance != type(uint256).max) {
            require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: insufficient allowance");
            unchecked {
                _approve(owner, spender, currentAllowance - amount);
            }
        }
    }
```

smart contract code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

//pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/math/SafeMathUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract FidelityImplementationContract is OwnableUpgradeable, ERC20Upgradeable {
    using SafeMathUpgradeable for uint256;
    
     // *-*-*-*-*-*-*_Attibutes_*-*-*-*-*-*-*

    // *-*-*-*-*-*-*_Constructor_*-*-*-*-*-*-*
    
    // struct EchelonReward is used to build rewards echelons
    struct EchelonReward {
        uint256 echelonMaxValue;
        uint256 percentage;
    }

    // stakeholders array
    address[] internal stakeholders;

    // minimum balance value since the last rewards distribution
    mapping(address => uint256) internal rewardableBalance;

    // timestamp to store when the next reward distribution will be possible
    uint256 internal nextRewardsAvailableTime;

    // duration between each reward distribution
    uint256 internal rewardsDuration;

    // reward percentage by tokens
    EchelonReward[] internal rewardsPercentageByTokens;


    // *-*-*-*-*-*-*_Constructor_*-*-*-*-*-*-*
    
    function init(uint256 initialTokens) initializer  public {
        // SET THE OWNER HERE
        __Ownable_init();
        __ERC20_init("FidelityToken", "FT");
        
        _mint(msg.sender, initialTokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
        fillRewardsPercentageByTokensOnStart();
        nextRewardsAvailableTime = block.timestamp.add(rewardsDuration);
        rewardsDuration = 2 minutes;
    }

    // *-*-*-*-*-*-*_Stakeholders_*-*-*-*-*-*-*

    /**
     * @notice A method to check if an address is a stakeholder.
     * @param _address The address to verify.
     * @return bool, uint256 Whether the address is a stakeholder, 
     * and if so its position in the stakeholders array.
    */
    function isStakeholder(address _address)
        public
        onlyOwner
        view
        returns(bool, uint256)
    {
        for (uint256 s = 0; s < stakeholders.length; s += 1){
            if (_address == stakeholders[s]) return (true, s);
        }
        return (false, 0);
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to add a stakeholder.
     * @param _stakeholder The stakeholder to add.
    */
    function addStakeholder(address _stakeholder)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        (bool _isStakeholder, ) = isStakeholder(_stakeholder);
        if(!_isStakeholder) {
            stakeholders.push(_stakeholder);
            rewardableBalance[_stakeholder] = 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to remove a stakeholder.
     * @param _stakeholder The stakeholder to remove.
    */
    function removeStakeholder(address _stakeholder)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        (bool _isStakeholder, uint256 s) = isStakeholder(_stakeholder);
        if(_isStakeholder){
            stakeholders[s] = stakeholders[stakeholders.length - 1];
            stakeholders.pop();
            rewardableBalance[_stakeholder] = 0;
        } 
    }


    // *-*-*-*-*-*-*_Rewards_*-*-*-*-*-*-*

    /** 
     * @notice A simple method that calculates the rewards of the given stakeholder.
     * @param _stakeholder The stakeholder to calculate rewards for.
    */
    function calculateReward(address _stakeholder)
        public
        onlyOwner
        view
        returns(uint256)
    {
        return getRewardableBalanceByStakeholder(_stakeholder) * getRewardPercentage(_stakeholder) / 100;
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to get the rewardable balance of the given stakeholder.
     * @param _stakeholder The stakeholder.
     * @return The amount of the rewardable tokens of the given stakeholder
    */
    function getRewardableBalanceByStakeholder(address _stakeholder)
        public
        onlyOwner
        view
        returns(uint256)
    {
        return rewardableBalance[_stakeholder];
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to get the reward percentage by balance.
     * @param _stakeholder The stakeholder.
     * @return The reward percentage according to the stakeholder's balance
    */
    function getRewardPercentage(address _stakeholder)
        public
        onlyOwner
        view
        returns(uint256)
    {
        if (0 != rewardsPercentageByTokens.length) {
            for (uint index = rewardsPercentageByTokens.length; index > 0; index--) {
                if (rewardableBalance[_stakeholder] >= rewardsPercentageByTokens[index - 1].echelonMaxValue) {
                    return rewardsPercentageByTokens[index - 1].percentage;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to get the reward percentage by balance.
     * @return The reward percentage according to the stakeholder's balance
    */
    function getRewardsPercentageByTokens() public onlyOwner view returns (EchelonReward[] memory) {
        return rewardsPercentageByTokens;
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to distribute rewards to all stakeholders.
    */
    function distributeRewards() 
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        if (block.timestamp >= nextRewardsAvailableTime) {
            for (uint256 s = 0; s < stakeholders.length; s += 1){
                address stakeholder = stakeholders[s];
                updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(stakeholder);
                uint256 reward = calculateReward(stakeholder);
                increaseAllowance(owner(), reward);
                transferFrom(owner(), stakeholder, reward);
                rewardableBalance[stakeholder] = balanceOf(stakeholder);
            }
            nextRewardsAvailableTime = block.timestamp.add(rewardsDuration);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to update the rewards percentage echlons.
     * @param newEchlonArray The new rewards echlons.
    */
    function updateRewardsPercentageByTokens(EchelonReward[] memory newEchlonArray) public onlyOwner {
        if (0 != newEchlonArray.length) {
            delete rewardsPercentageByTokens;
            for (uint index = 0; index < newEchlonArray.length; index++) {
                EchelonReward memory echelon;
                echelon.echelonMaxValue = newEchlonArray[index].echelonMaxValue * 10 ** uint256(decimals());
                echelon.percentage = newEchlonArray[index].percentage;
                rewardsPercentageByTokens[index] = echelon;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to initialize the reward percntages.
    */
    function fillRewardsPercentageByTokensOnStart() private onlyOwner {
        rewardsPercentageByTokens.push(EchelonReward(
            {
                echelonMaxValue : 100 * 10 ** uint256(decimals()),
                percentage : 1
            }));

        rewardsPercentageByTokens.push(EchelonReward(
            {
                echelonMaxValue : 500 * 10 ** uint256(decimals()),
                percentage : 2
            }));

        rewardsPercentageByTokens.push(EchelonReward(
            {
                echelonMaxValue : 1000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals()),
                percentage : 3
            }));

        rewardsPercentageByTokens.push(EchelonReward(
            {
                echelonMaxValue : 10000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals()),
                percentage : 4
            }));
        
        rewardsPercentageByTokens.push(EchelonReward(
            {
                echelonMaxValue : 50000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals()),
                percentage : 5
            }));
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to update the rewardable balance for the given stakeholder.
     * @param _stakeholder The stakeholder.
    */
    function updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(address _stakeholder) public onlyOwner {
        if (balanceOf(_stakeholder) < rewardableBalance[_stakeholder]) {
            rewardableBalance[_stakeholder] = balanceOf(_stakeholder);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to update the rewardable balance for all the stakeholders.
    */
    function updateRewardableBalances() public onlyOwner {
        for (uint index = 0; index < stakeholders.length; index++) {
            updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(stakeholders[index]);
        } 
    }


    // *-*-*-*-*-*-*_Transactions_*-*-*-*-*-*-*

    /**
     * @notice A method to send tokens from the retailer to the customer.
     * @param retailer The retailer address.
     * @param customer The customer address.
     * @param tokens The amount of tokens to send.
    */
    function sendTokensFromRetailerToCustomer(address retailer, address customer, uint256 tokens) public onlyOwner {
        increaseAllowance(retailer, tokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
        transferFrom(retailer, customer, tokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(customer);
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(retailer);
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to send tokens from the customer to the retailer.
     * @param retailer The retailer address.
     * @param customer The customer address.
     * @param tokens The amount of tokens to send.
    */
    function sendTokensFromCustomerToRetailer(address retailer, address customer, uint256 tokens) public onlyOwner {
        increaseAllowance(customer, tokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
        transferFrom(customer, retailer, tokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(customer);
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(retailer);
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to enable customers to send tokens from one retailer to another.
     * @param retailerSource The retailer source address.
     * @param walletSource The customer address in the source retailer.
     * @param walletDestination The customer address in the target retailer.
     * @param tokensToSend The amount of tokens to send.
     * @param feesForFidelityPercent The percentage of transaction fees for Fidelity.
     * @param feesForRetailerSourcePercent The percentage of transaction fees for the source retailer.
    */
    function tansfertFromRetailerToAnother(address retailerSource, address walletSource, address walletDestination, uint256 tokensToSend,
            uint256 feesForFidelityPercent, uint256 feesForRetailerSourcePercent) public onlyOwner {
                
        uint256 feesForFidelity = ((tokensToSend * feesForFidelityPercent) / 100) * 10 ** uint256(decimals());
        uint256 feesForRetailerSource = ((tokensToSend * feesForRetailerSourcePercent) / 100) * 10 ** uint256(decimals());
        
        increaseAllowance(walletSource, (tokensToSend * 10 ** uint256(decimals())) - feesForFidelity - feesForRetailerSource);
        transferFrom(walletSource, walletDestination, (tokensToSend * 10 ** uint256(decimals())) - feesForFidelity - feesForRetailerSource);
        
        increaseAllowance(walletSource, feesForRetailerSource);
        transferFrom(walletSource, retailerSource, feesForRetailerSource);
        
        increaseAllowance(walletSource, feesForFidelity);
        transferFrom(walletSource, owner(), feesForFidelity);
        
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(retailerSource);
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(walletSource);
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(walletDestination);
        updateRewardableBalancePerAddress(owner());
    }

    /**
     * @notice A method to mint extra tokens.
     * @param tokens The amount of tokens to mint.
    */
    function mintExtraTokens(uint256 tokens) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(owner(), tokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
    }
    
    /**
     * @notice A method to burn tokens.
     * @param tokens The amount of tokens to burn.
    */
    function burnTokens(uint256 tokens) public onlyOwner {
        _burn(owner(), tokens * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
    }
    
    /**
     * @notice A method to get the formatted balance of the given stakeholder.
     * @param _stakeholder The stakeholder.
     * @return The formatted balance of the given stakeholder
    */
    function getFormattedBalance(address _stakeholder)
        public
        view
        returns(uint256)
    {
        return balanceOf(_stakeholder) / 10 ** uint256(decimals());
    }
    
}
```

the problem happen when I try to send token with the function sendTokensFromCustomerToRetailer() , when I use my address which is the address of the owner of the smart contract as a customer the transaction success , but when I use an other address as the address of the customer the transaction fail **I mean only the transaction happen from my address to another I can't for example make transaction from another address to my address they always fail**

here the transaction fail when I use an other address as  customer address (not the address of the owner ):
[image]

this is a link for the transaction that fail : [link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x125298ea12244853d981ad1d362d9ec17f0577352d32df25c3506ce70081dc32)

link for successful transaction : [link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xdcf30526c653ae8f8ec398f4cf9b0cf0d4b707ba77c1584ceb4be9bf099e1543)

Comment: Please, can you share all smart contract code?

Comment: ok i will share it

Comment: Can you add more information about error and about the single operations that you did for encounter the error?

Comment: ok i will add more information

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction revert because `sendTokensFromCustomerToRetailer` function call internal the `updateRewardableBalancePerAddress` function but this function has `onlyOwner` modifier.

When you call `updateRewardableBalancePerAddress` function `sendTokensFromCustomerToRetailer` then `msg.sender` address is the `contract` address.

Try to remove `onlyOnwer` modifier and mark as a `internal` then only contract call this function.

If you don't want to mark as a internal function then try to call function with `delegate` call. Here is the [Example](https://solidity-by-example.org/delegatecall/) of the delegate call.

Comment: I think the problem is in transferFrom function because the transaction throw an error : Fail with error 'ERC20: insufficient allowance' and this error is coming from ERC20Upgradeable exactly from the function _spendAllowance() , I removed onlyOwner from updateRewardableBalancePerAddress () and always the transaction fail : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xcd9788a87db1cf9a19a0ae9002c604e6f94335a213ca215df4156250a985e212